# Brute force passwords in Java

Tags: java

I made this little code to see what brute forcing is like. I made this with a complete guess on how it works. This code works fine but it seems to take much much longer than it really should. I have the `Scanner` there so I can tell the program what password it is searching for. I have the `timeMillis` also just for personal reasons to see how long it takes to find a password.

I have the

```
System.out.println(newPass);
```

to see if I ever run into errors where would I run into it. The way my code works is that it loops chars^length times until it hits the password.

If there is any way I can improve this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    static String newPass = "";
    static String chars = "0123456789aABbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyzZ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String password = userIn.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Is using symbols an option? if so type in [Y] if not type in [N]");
        String choose = userIn.nextLine();
        boolean decideSymb = true;
        boolean again = true;
        while (again == true) {
            if (choose.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                again = false;
            } else if (choose.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                again = false;
                decideSymb = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Try again! \nIs using symbols an option? if so type in [Y] if not type in [N]");
                choose = userIn.nextLine();
            }
        }
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        crack(password, decideSymb);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long milliSecs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(end - start);
        ;
        long secs = milliSecs / 1000;
        long mins = secs / 60;
        long hours = mins / 60;
        long days = hours / 24;
        long years = days / 365;
        days -= (years * 365);
        hours -= (days * 24);
        mins -= (hours * 60);
        secs -= (mins * 60);
        milliSecs -= (secs * 1000);
        System.out.println("The password is: " + newPass);
        if (years > 0) {
            if (years == 1) {
                System.out.println("it took\n" + years + "year\n" + days + " days\n" + hours + " hours\n" + mins
                        + " mins\n" + secs + " secs\n" + milliSecs + " milliseconds\nto find the password");
            } else {
                System.out.println("it took\n" + years + "years\n" + days + " days\n" + hours + " hours\n" + mins
                        + " mins\n" + secs + " secs\n" + milliSecs + " milliseconds\nto find the password");
            }
        } else if (days > 0) {
            if (days == 1) {
                System.out.println("it took\n" + days + " day\n" + hours + " hours\n" + mins + " mins\n" + secs
                        + " secs\n" + milliSecs + " milliseconds\nto find the password");
            } else {
                System.out.println("it took\n" + days + " days\n" + hours + " hours\n" + mins + " mins\n" + secs
                        + " secs\n" + milliSecs + " milliseconds\nto find the password");
            }
        } else if (hours > 0) {
            if (hours == 1) {
                System.out.println("it took\n" + hours + " hour\n" + mins + " mins\n" + secs + " secs\n" + milliSecs
                        + " milliseconds\nto find the password");
            } else {
                System.out.println("it took\n" + hours + " hours\n" + mins + " mins\n" + secs + " secs\n" + milliSecs
                        + " milliseconds\nto find the password");
            }
        } else if (mins > 0) {
            if (mins == 1) {
                System.out.println("it took\n" + mins + " min\n" + secs + " secs\n" + milliSecs
                        + " milliseconds\nto find the password");
            } else {
                System.out.println("it took\n" + mins + " mins\n" + secs + " secs\n" + milliSecs
                        + " milliseconds\nto find the password");
            }
        } else if (secs > 0) {
            if (secs == 1) {
                System.out.println("it took\n" + secs + " sec\n" + milliSecs + " milliseconds\nto find the password");
            } else {
                System.out.println("it took\n" + secs + " secs\n" + milliSecs + " milliseconds\nto find the password");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("it took\n" + milliSecs + " milliseconds\nto find the password");
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static void crack(String password, boolean decideSymb) {
        if (decideSymb == true) {
            chars = "1234567890#%&@aABbCcDdEeFfGgHh!IiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRr$SsTtUuVvWwXxYyzZ";
        }
        for (int length = 2; length <= 15; length++) {
            newPass = "";
            for (int n = 0; n < length; n++) {
                newPass += "0";
            }
            int lastInd = length - 1;
            while (!newPass.equals(password)) {
                String end = "";
                for (int n = 0; n < newPass.length(); n++) {
                    end += "Z";
                }
                if (newPass.equals(end)) {
                    break;
                }
                int indInChars = chars.indexOf(newPass.charAt(lastInd));
                if (indInChars < chars.length() && indInChars >= 0) {
                    boolean t = true;
                    int howManyZs = 0;
                    while (t == true) {
                        if (newPass.charAt(newPass.length() - 1 - howManyZs) == 'Z') {
                            howManyZs++;
                        } else {
                            t = false;
                        }
                    }
                    String reset0s = "";
                    for (int l = 0; l < howManyZs; l++) {
                        reset0s += "0";
                    }
                    if (lastInd < newPass.length() - 1 && lastInd > 0) {
                        lastInd--;
                        indInChars = chars.indexOf(newPass.charAt(lastInd)) + 1;
                        newPass = newPass.substring(0, lastInd) + chars.charAt(indInChars)
                                + newPass.substring(lastInd + 1);
                    } else if (newPass.length() - howManyZs == 1) {
                        newPass = chars.substring(chars.indexOf(newPass.charAt(0)) + 1,
                                chars.indexOf(newPass.charAt(0)) + 2) + reset0s;
                    } else if (newPass.length() - howManyZs > 1 && howManyZs != 0) {
                        newPass = newPass.substring(0, newPass.length() - 1 - howManyZs)
                                + chars.substring(chars.indexOf(newPass.charAt(newPass.length() - 1 - howManyZs)) + 1,
                                        chars.indexOf(newPass.charAt(newPass.length() - 1 - howManyZs)) + 2)
                                + reset0s;
                    } else {
                        indInChars = chars.indexOf(newPass.charAt(lastInd)) + 1;
                        newPass = newPass.substring(0, lastInd) + chars.charAt(indInChars);
                    }
                    System.out.println(newPass);
                }
            }
            if (newPass.equals(password)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind I am not gonna use this for malicious reasons. Plus, most software is invulnerable to brute force. This is merely out of fun.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Do while you must

> ```
>     System.out.println("Is using symbols an option? if so type in [Y] if not type in [N]");
>     String choose = userIn.nextLine();
>     boolean decideSymb = true;
>     boolean again = true;
>     while (again == true) {
>         if (choose.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
>             again = false;
>         } else if (choose.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
>             again = false;
>             decideSymb = false;
>         } else {
>             System.out.println("Try again! \nIs using symbols an option? if so type in [Y] if not type in [N]");
>             choose = userIn.nextLine();
>         }
>     }
> ```

You have some awkward-feeling repeated code in here (the prompt for input). This can be refactored into a cleaner, more natural feeling `do/while` loop:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Is using symbols an option? if so type in [Y] if not type in [N]");
    String choose = userIn.nextLine();
} while(!choose.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choose.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));
```

By changing this to a `do/while`, we were able to remove those clunky `if` statements along with the two flag variables.

The above loop will continuously ask for input until proper input is given.

## Or use a pattern you can

Instead of using a loop to shorten the above code, you could use the `Scanner`'s built-in [`next(Pattern pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.util.regex.Pattern)). This will ensure that you only get input that follows your specified pattern.

First, create a `final Pattern` in a class field so you can easily access it in the code:

```
public static final Pattern yesOrNo = Pattern.compile("(y|n)", CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

*The above regex should only pass for either y, n, Y, or N. Also, it may be better to compile the regex in the main method itself.*

Then, in your code, instead of having the loop, you can simply write:

```
System.out.println("Is using symbols an option? if so type in [Y] if not type in [N]");
String choose = userIn.next(yesOrNo);
```

I believe this is a much better solution.

---

## Too far for a single letter

> ```
>         if (years == 1) {
>             System.out.println("it took\n" + years + "year\n" + days + " days\n" + hours + " hours\n" + mins
>                     + " mins\n" + secs + " secs\n" + milliSecs + " milliseconds\nto find the password");
>         } else {
>             System.out.println("it took\n" + years + "years\n" + days + " days\n" + hours + " hours\n" + mins
>                     + " mins\n" + secs + " secs\n" + milliSecs + " milliseconds\nto find the password");
>         }
> ```

You have two entirely separate conditional statements just to add a single character? That's a waste, and it makes your code look ugly.

Honestly, I don't think you'll even need to worry about that "s".

1. The chances of it being exactly `1` are very low.
2. It's such a small thing that most applications ignore.

However, if you *really* want to have that "s" there, use a ternary instead:

```
System.out.println("it took\n" + years + "year" + (years == 1 ? "s" : "") + "\n" + days + " days\n" + hours + " hours\n" + mins + " mins\n" + secs + " secs\n" + milliSecs + " milliseconds\nto find the password");
```

---

## The date is *exactly*...

This chunk of code here:

> ```
>     long secs = milliSecs / 1000;
>     long mins = secs / 60;
>     long hours = mins / 60;
>     long days = hours / 24;
>     long years = days / 365;
>     days -= (years * 365);
>     hours -= (days * 24);
>     mins -= (hours * 60);
>     secs -= (mins * 60);
> ```

Doesn't belong. It should be extracted into a separate method that accepts the `milliSecs` variable. As for `returning`, it could probably return a custom class that looks like this:

```
public class TimeData {
    private final long secs;
    private final long mins;
    ...
}
```

with getters for each field. This will make your code more OO.

If you want to be extra OOP-y, you can put the method that generates the `TimeData` in this `TimeData` class, make it `static`, and have it return an instance of `TimeData` with filled data.

## Over-complicating the time printing

Again, you are over-complicating the time printing section. In my opinion, it is perfectly okay to have something like:

> "It took 0 days, 0 hours, 24 minutes, 13 seconds, and 1 millisecond."

Those 0's there don't harm the UI at all. Instead of having that huge conditional chain in your code, you should just use `System.out.printf` and print out all the time values you have.

Going back to OOP, you could extract this into the `TimeData`'s `toString` method.

Comment: I am not sure why I didn't think of doing a Do While loop... I can be a real idiot sometimes. Thank you for the detailed feedback and all I really appreciate it. I updated my code and you should check it out and give me feedback again if you can.

Answer (score 7):

### Pluralisation

You have a lot of code dealing with this, and it's both repetitive and not quite right (checks only for the plural-ness of the first item, so you might get "it took 1 min 1 secs 1 milliseconds").

Something like this would be a start:

```
private static String pluralFormat(String word, long value) {
    return value.toString() + " " + word + (value == 1 ? "s" : "") + "\n";
}

System.out.println(
    "it took\n"
    + pluralFormat("year", years)
    + pluralFormat("day", days)
    + pluralFormat("hour", hours)
    + pluralFormat("min", mins)
    + pluralFormat("sec", secs)
    + pluralFormat("millisecond", milliSecs)
    + "to find the password"
);
```

Or you could use separate `println`s for each line to avoid manually appending the newline character.

### Cracking algorithm

It's a little hard to follow what's going on here.

First, usually "cracking" a password means that you know a hashed password (the output of `hashfunction(password)`) and you crack it by finding what value of `password` gives you that hash. Here there is no hash function, you're just building string permutations until you've arrived at `password`. This is fine, I just wanted to make a note.

Second, since I'm not fully sure what's going on with the `howManyZs` and your algorithm in general, I'll just offer some structural suggestions:

**Repeating strings**

In a couple of places you build a string of `n` repeated characters. You could turn that into a static utility method:

```
private static String repeatString(String s, int n) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);
    while (n-- > 0) {
        sb.append(s);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

so that you'd end up with, for example

```
String end = repeatString("Z", newpass.length());
```

**Parameters and variable scopes**

To keep data more encapsulated and make your `crack` function more reusable, I recommend declaring it like this:

```
private static String crack(String password, String possibleChars)
```

- Take in `possibleChars` directly, and let the caller pass either `chars` or `chars + symbols` as needed.
- Return the cracked password instead of storing it in a global field `newPass`.

Comment: I am not sure exactly how I can use hashing to crack passwords because from what I understand hashing takes a bit more time. However thanks for all the help! I updated my code and you should check it out again and give me feedback if you can :)