# Brute force passwords in Java - follow-up

Tags: java

Here is the updated code. The original question can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114594/brute-force-passwords-in-java/).

I would love it if you posted more ways I can improve this code. I am still fairly new to Java so I am not entirely sure how to make it any better.

```
package hexTox;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    static String newPass = "";
    static String chars = "0123456789aABbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyzZ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String password = userIn.nextLine();
        String choose;
        boolean decideSymb = true;
        do {
            System.out.println("Is using symbols an option? if so type in [Y] if not type in [N]");
            choose = userIn.nextLine();
        } while (!choose.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choose.equalsIgnoreCase("n")); //This was a long while loop with a lot of if and elses, thanks to SirPython's notice I changed it as he suggested.
        if (choose.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            decideSymb = false;
        }
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        crack(password, decideSymb);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long milliSecs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(end - start);
        System.out.println("The password is: " + newPass);
        time(milliSecs);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static void time(long milliSecs) { //I put this in a method rather than the Main method and changed it up as BenC and SirPython noted
        long secs = milliSecs / 1000;
        long mins = secs / 60;
        long hours = mins / 60;
        long days = hours / 24;
        long years = days / 365;
        days -= (years * 365);
        hours -= (days * 24);
        mins -= (hours * 60);
        secs -= (mins * 60);
        milliSecs -= (secs * 1000);
        System.out.println("it took " + pluralFormat("year", years) + pluralFormat("day", days)
                + pluralFormat("hour", hours) + pluralFormat("min", mins) + pluralFormat("sec", secs)
                + pluralFormat("millisecond", milliSecs) + "to find the password");
    }

    private static String pluralFormat(String word, long value) { //This here was put as BenC noted to make my code more efficient
        return Long.toString(value) + " " + word + (value > 1 ? "s" : "") + ", ";
    }

    private static void crack(String password, boolean decideSymb) {
        if (decideSymb == true) {
            chars = "0123456789#%&@aABbCcDdEeFfGgHh!IiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRr$SsTtUuVvWwXxYyzZ"; //In my original code it started with 1 and now it starts with 0 as it is suppose to do.
        }
        for (int length = 2; length <= 15; length++) {
            newPass = "";
            newPass = repeatString("0", length);
            int lastInd = length - 1;
            while (!newPass.equals(password)) {
                String end = repeatString("Z", newPass.length());
                if (newPass.equals(end)) {
                    break;
                }
                int indInChars = chars.indexOf(newPass.charAt(lastInd));
                if (indInChars < chars.length() && indInChars >= 0) {
                    boolean t = true;
                    int howManyZs = 0; //This will replace that last Zs that are in order with 0s then update the one in front +1 char. For Example abcZZZ will evaluate to abD000 and will go on.
                    while (t == true) {
                        if (newPass.charAt(newPass.length() - 1 - howManyZs) == 'Z') {
                            howManyZs++;
                        } else {
                            t = false;
                        }
                    }
                    String reset0s = "";
                    for (int l = 0; l < howManyZs; l++) {
                        reset0s += "0";
                    }
                    if (lastInd < newPass.length() - 1 && lastInd > 0) {
                        lastInd--;
                        indInChars = chars.indexOf(newPass.charAt(lastInd)) + 1;
                        newPass = newPass.substring(0, lastInd) + chars.charAt(indInChars)
                                + newPass.substring(lastInd + 1);
                    } else if (newPass.length() - howManyZs == 1) {
                        newPass = chars.substring(chars.indexOf(newPass.charAt(0)) + 1,
                                chars.indexOf(newPass.charAt(0)) + 2) + reset0s;
                    } else if (newPass.length() - howManyZs > 1 && howManyZs != 0) {
                        newPass = newPass.substring(0, newPass.length() - 1 - howManyZs)
                                + chars.substring(chars.indexOf(newPass.charAt(newPass.length() - 1 - howManyZs)) + 1,
                                        chars.indexOf(newPass.charAt(newPass.length() - 1 - howManyZs)) + 2)
                                + reset0s;
                    } else {
                        indInChars = chars.indexOf(newPass.charAt(lastInd)) + 1;
                        newPass = newPass.substring(0, lastInd) + chars.charAt(indInChars);
                    }
                    System.out.println(newPass);
                }
            }
            if (newPass.equals(password)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static String repeatString(String s, int n) { //This here was put as BenC noted to make my code more efficient
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);
        while (n-- > 0) {
            sb.append(s);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: To prevent this from looking like a possible duplicate, consider adding the specific changes that were made.

Comment: Can you give a brief explanation of how your brute-forcing approach works? I'm also intrigued by why you're counting the number of Zs (`howManyZs`)...

Comment: @h.j.k. Sorry for not telling you earlier. Anyways I put it in as a comment in the code explaining what it is. By the way I am also working on a newer and faster way of brute forcing right now and will try to put up the code when done!

Comment: @OybekKamolov ok, thanks for the update... so it starts with `a` and loop upwards by going to `b`, then `abcZZZ` to `abD000` and so on?

Comment: Brute force isn't really a nice (albeit sometimes the only) solution. It will be `O(n^m)` in worst case, where `n` is the length of the password and `m` is the length of the charset being used. (*please correct me if I am wrong with the Big O notation*)

Comment: @Emz You are correct. I did the math on for example 8^62 and that throws 9.8079715e+55 which is A LOT of zeros. However it is entirely possible to make the whole cracking go fast. Here is a article about a brute force on Windows. http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/12/25-gpu-cluster-cracks-every-standard-windows-password-in-6-hours/ At the end of the day you just need a god like PC, which not all of us have the money for :C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Make use of constants**

Instead of having `static String chars` with the default numbers and letters then in the middle of code overriding it with symbols as well, I suggest instead storing two `static final String chars` and `static final String symbols`, if you choose to use symbols as well, simply add it to the `string activeCharset`. That way it is easier at a first glance to see what characters exists, instead of having to scroll mid-way down the code.

```
private static final String CHARACTERS  = "0123456789aABbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyzZ";
private static final String SYMBOLS     = "#%&@!$";

private static String activeCharset     = characters;
```

You then add to your `activeCharset` instead of working with `boolean decideSymb`

**Magic values**

```
for (int length = 2; length <= 15; length++) {
```

I again recommend to store the `2` and `15` as constants. Tell what they  represent, right now you have to read and understand the code to figure it out.

**Return values**

This is a more of an opinion.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
crack(password, decideSymb);
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Your `crack` can return the time it took for it to execute, simply by having `long start = System.currentTimeMillis();` in the start and subtracting it from `long end = System.currentTimeMillis();` in the end.

*Reasoning: If measuring the time it takes for the brute-force algorithm then it makes sense that it's crack method keeps track of it.*

```
// get password from user
Scanner userIn = new Scanner (System.in);
password = userIn.nextLine();

// ask if symbols should be used
do {
    System.out.println("Is using symbols an option? if so type in [Y] if not type in [N]");
    choose = userIn.nextLine();
} while (!choose.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choose.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));

// if it is then add them
if (choose.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    activeCharset += SYMBOLS; 
}
```

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

---

*Footnote: I think it is great that you are doing follow up rounds on the code. It shows that you do actually care about the feedback.*

Comment: @OybekKamolov, I stand corrected, you should not use `try-with-resource`. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042139/java-tryscanner-scan-new-scannersystem-in-causing-an-exception)

Comment: Try-with-resources can work. Note that closing the scanner closes the underlying stream. If you close the scanner on `System.in`, then you cannot reopen it.